# how to set lower_case_table_names = 1 on ubuntu-18.04 mariadb mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

Installed through $ sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client

Please help me where i need to change for this `lower_case_table_names = 1`?

Comment: What exactly is that?

Comment: Caution:  The answer depends on what version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

my OS ubuntu, Mysql version is 5.7.*

update file /etc/mysql/my.cnf, (must add under the section [mysqld])

```
[mysqld]

lower_case_table_names=1
```

then restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

Caution:  In MySQL 8.0, establishing a non-default value for `lower_case_table_names` must be done before installing.  This is because of the new Data Dictionary that is implemented in InnoDB tables.

(I provide this for future readers who might assume the answer for 5.7 still applies.)